# How to display non-mobile version of website on iPhone/iPad uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I am trying to display the non-mobile version of a website (for websites that suck at mobile versions) within a uiwebsite.

Here is my code. It changes the user agent but still does not display the desktop version of a website.

```
NSURL *urlValue = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlValue];
NSString *newUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7";
[request setValue:newUserAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: This does change the user agent (i checked via http://www.useragentstring.com/ ) but still doesnt display non-mobile version